# How to blur background layout on EditText event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

I'm currently encounter a difficulty, I'd like to blur (change the alpha would be okay too) the background (all views except my `EditText`) when I click on my `EditText`, and get back to normal when I leave it.

Does anyone already encountered that problem ?

I've tried to put a FrameLayout into the parent, set its alpha to 0.7f, and bring the `EditText` to Front when the edittext is focused, but I don't have the result I've expected.

Here a hierarchy of my layout:

> Relative {
>
> > ImageView
> >
> > LinearLayout
>
> ```
>       TextView 
>       EditText 
>       EditText 
>       Button 
>
> FrameLayout (used to "blur" background")
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the solution found was to put all my widgets into the same relativeLayout so I can "play" with the z-index, bringing the Edittext to front when I received a click then bring and setAlpha to the FrameLayout used to hide background.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. But If I were you, I would create a `CustomAlertDiaglog` with only `EditText` field in `onClickListener` of the `EditText`. This will automatically shown in a pop up window and all the views in the background will be dimmed.

Here is a good [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) how to use the `CustomAlertDialog`

Comment: That is not what I wanna do, I'd like to make my form interactive, like that when a user is clicking on one field the edittext is moving up over all others view and it is very distinct from the rest.

I wanna a reproduce a feature I've on website, but for my application form.
Do you see what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to blur your input bitmap image:

```
 Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap input) {
            RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(this);
            Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

            ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, alloc.getElement());
            blur.setRadius(12);
            blur.setInput(alloc);

            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig());
            Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);
            blur.forEach(outAlloc);
            outAlloc.copyTo(result);

            rsScript.destroy();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Can u please read the question before posting code that don't even close to  what I've asked